# Vue project does not Navbar @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My navbar search form does not work

```
<form action="" method="post" class="search">
    <input type="text"  name="" placeholder="поиск" class="input" v-model="allsearch"/>
    <a href="#" @click='clicksearch()'>0</a>
</form>
```

**My script**:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    data () {
      return {
        allsearch:''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clicksearch(){
        console.log(this.allsearch)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**`App.vue`**:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navbar />
        <router-view/>
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<style>
  @import "assets/css/default.css";
  @import "assets/css/header.css";
  @import "assets/css/shortcodes.css";
  @import "assets/css/core.css";
  @import "assets/css/style.css";
</style>

<script>
    import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
    import Footer from "./components/Footer"
    export default {
        components: {Navbar, Footer}
    }
</script>
```

**Router**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Posts from './views/Posts'
import Single from './views/Single';
import Smartigadget from './views/Smartigadget';
import Applesmartphone from './views/Applesmartphone';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'posts',
        component: Posts,
    },
    {
        path: '/:id',
        name: 'Single',
        component: Single,
        props:true
    },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

export default router
```

**Error**:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Try out `<a href="#" @click.prevent='clicksearch()'>0</a>`

Comment: no does not work

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/VFG7Pj2vvon5rA photo error

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that component.  Try to post a reproduction of the problem at https://www.codesandbox.io

Comment: <a href="#" @click='clicksearch'>0</a> should work

Comment: no dont work.....

Answer (score 0):

```
@click='clicksearch()'
```

should be

```
@click='clicksearch'
```

otherwise `@click` gets bound to whatever clicksearch returns